How do I locate the problems when my TexStudio compile is showing row upon row of unicode problems?
I got up this morning to work on my PhD dissertation, to be faced with:, .The file looked fine when I went to bed. I can't locate the problem.
The start of the lines are:
I'm working in TexStudio. How do I locate and fix this problem? At one point I did get .tex lines where the unicode allegedly was, but they all referred to the first line of my document, which sets up the packages, and calls the chapters, etc.
Some of my journal article references (in refs.bib) have special characters, because of people's names. I have not changed the refs.bib file since the start of April, confirmed by the date of the file on my drive. There are also amsmath contents in the chapters.
I don't know what to do to fix this. I had done some typing in a chapter (called with include) but deleting all that typing and even commenting out the include still produces the problem below.
I don't even know where to start looking for the cause. The document was compiling to 219 pages, if that gives some indication of how much searching I need to do.
Thanks in advance.
Edit: hexdump of head of main .tex file that calls all other .tex and .bib and .glo files
 0000000 2025 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d
 0000010 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d
 *
 0000040 2d2d 250a 5220 7065 726f 2074 6c43 7361
 0000050 2073 5428 6968 2073 7369 6120 4c20 5461
 0000060 5865 6532 6420 636f 6d75 6e65 2974 2020
 0000070 2a2a 2a2a 2a2a 2a2a 2a2a 2a2a 2a2a 2a2a
 0000080 2a2a 2a2a 0a2a 2025 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d
 0000090 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d
 *


I tried to paste a couple of lines of the unicode in, but the system prevented me from asking this question if I had the unicode in. :(

Make a backup copy of your tex file.  It looks like something has messed up the character encoding of the file.  Can you use a hex editor to read the first few bytes of the file and paste that here?

Do you have a link to a hex editor that I can use? I'm on a Mac.

On a command line: hexdump filename.tex | head

I have 17 .tex files that go in the includes plus a .glo file plus a .bib file, so 20 files including the main .tex that sets up the packages, references, glossary, etc.

I have constructed a new folder and am reconstructing the project, file by file, and then recompiling. Both the main .tex file and the references are compiling fine, so I have zero idea where the unicode problem is.

You can also try file yourfile.tex, and the file command will show you a guess about what you have.

Please tell me you have a backup.

Yes, I back up to the cloud and have been duplicating and renaming tex files each day. From what I can work out, it looks like the corruption is somehow in the options or tools setup in TexStudio.

Look like when you are trying to edit as plain text file a binary file (like a program file or a docx document). Use the file tool.
